# How do I Request a gzip javascript file from AWS CloudFront and S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, webpack, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm looking to optimize my website's bundle size with compression. Just for starters, I'm using webpack and the compression-webpack-plugin to create a gizp file from my compiled javascript. All my assets are hosted on S3 and served through CloudFront. Also new to this kind of optimization.

```
new CompressionPlugin({
 test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
 filename: "[path].gz[query]",
 algorithm: "gzip",
})
```

my s3 bucket. looks like this

```
bucket /
 index.html
 main-92540b8c5cf0e7107a73.js.gz
```

above js.gz file has the "content-encoding: gzip" meta data field set. Toal size is 86.0 KB

S3 CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

index.html is looking for this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-92540b8c5cf0e7107a73.js"></script>
```

My CloudFront distribution has Compress Objects Automatically set to true. Although I'm sure thats necessary since my file is already compressed.

With all that set, I see this error in my console for my js.file

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

If I check my Request and Response headers they look like

[image]

I believe the issue that I'm facing is that there is no Accept-Encoding: gzip header set in my request. But I'm unclear as to how I should add it.

My question is, am I correct about the missing header? or is there something else that I missed in this?

Comment: If you enable “compress objects automatically” on your CloudFront distribution, you should get gzipped responses automagically.

Comment: CloudFront needs to know that the browser requesting the files can accept a gzipped file as well, correct?

Comment: Nope... Never done this, from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by removing the .gz extension on my compressed files. Also added content-length header to my s3 buckets cors configuration